# Firebase push notification - Android users send notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am a new learner on android development. So that I want to know some information related to FCM. I have looked at many sites questions and tutorial, I saw, how android users receive notification from Firebase which send by manual. The think I want is, how android user send the notification message to Firebase and Firebase continue to spread or push the notification received from the user to other users? (Any idea or tutorial or another QA related)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send user to user messages you have 2 ways

1. you need server side
2. you can use cloud firebase function and realtime database

   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

there you can write your server side code

Comment: Need own server side or server side of Firebase?
What does server side code look like?